# Sturdy privacy barrier on rooftop

Tags: wind, usa

My townhome has a rooftop deck. A waist-high wall about 10 feet long separates it from my neighbor's deck. The other walls are taller, maybe shoulder height (~5 feet).

I would like to construct some sort of barrier, at least 6 feet tall, in front of the shorter wall, for privacy between me and my neighbor, as well as for blocking wind. My initial thought was bamboo, which would look great. However, it can get *very* windy where I live—up to 70 mph, although this is rare (~30 mph is more typical). The higher walls of my deck of course block some of this wind, but on super windy days, my deck furniture gets tossed around, so the wind felt on the deck can be significant.

I'm wondering what my options are. Ideally, it would stand up to normal windy days (up to 30 or even 50 mph).

Comment: How long is the waist-high wall?

Comment: Good point, I added it to the question. It's about 10 feet, although I don't necessarily need to cover all of it. An 8 ft barrier would be enough.

Comment: This is bordering on a shopping question, which is off-topic. A web search for `fence panels` or `privacy panels` would get you much more than we could (or should) provide. The solution also hinges on what mounting options you have, which you haven't addressed at all.

Comment: @isherwood OK. Pretend I'm building it myself then. What would you recommend? I'm trying to figure out *what* type of material or barrier I might need. All the privacy panels I've seen in stores and online look pretty flimsy and wouldn't hold up to much wind.

Comment: That's because they don't. The structure they're mounted to does, and we don't know what options you have on your property owner's roof.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'd like to help, but I don't know how aside from writing a broad-scoped primer on fence construction. That's not what this site is about, though.

Comment: @isherwood I understand. I'll take a picture when I get home—I'm not aware of anything that looks like it could be used to mount a fence. I was thinking I'd need some sort of barrier with a super heavy base, and I've never seen anything like that before.

Comment: A lot depends on the exact structure of the surrounding ~5' walls, and on what constructions you are allowed to add. - Can you run a beam, e.g. a 2" x 8" @ 10', from the top of one surrounding wall to the other?

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri I can do pretty much anything (I am the owner & do not have an HOA or other restrictions), but only on my half of the shared wall. Adding a beam like that should be no problem. I think pictures will help give a better idea—I'll upload some in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested construction:

[image: suggestion sketch]

I've depicted an overlapping jalousie privacy fence but I haven't put in all the details. "Privacy fence" construction is sort of a solved problem.

The fence does not need to be very strong because the beam supports it along its entire length.

Comment: This looks like the way to go, thank you! I think in this case I would just buy the privacy fence pre-built. Looks like there's lots of great options out there. The tops of the side walls are covered by some sort of metal plating (for sealing), but I believe I could use machine screws to attach the support beam to them?

Comment: Try to pry up the metal plating. If it is not solidly attached then you'll have to re-cement it. Then you can drill and tap for machine screws.

Comment: Weighted canvas curtain? Even 8 foot by 6 foot will produce tremendous forces in a 50mph wind. Nest let it through or be ready for structural problems. Let the thing wiggle when the wind hits 20mph. Perhaps weighted strips even, on a pipe frame.